# Android Search Activity

Tags: java, android, database, search, button

I have created an application which is just a list view with some values in it and each time I click an item, it starts a new intent. I want my list to be searchable, so I have added a search button on top of it.

I have seen some examples that uses local databases but I did not find a complete tutorial on how to implement this in my application.

What is the best way to do this?
Can anyone reference me to a good site with examples or explain to me how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this demo.

I have implemented the ListView with search features based on the text entered in to EditText.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    searchTextLength = searchEditText.getText().length();
    m_orders.clear();
    m_orders = new ArrayList<SearchData>();
    //SearchData o1 = new SearchData();
    SearchData o[]=new SearchData[search_list.length];
    for(int i=0; i<search_list.length; i++)
    {
        if(searchTextLength <= search_list[i].length())
        {
            if(searchEditText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) search_list[i].subSequence(0, searchTextLength)))
            {
                o[i]=new SearchData();
                o[i].setTitleName(search_list[i]);
                o[i].setsubTitleName(subTitle_list[i]);
                m_orders.add(o[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.search_row, m_orders);
    lv.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);
    m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //getOrders();

    //lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchActivity.this,R.layout.search_layout , arr_sort));
}
```

Hope it will help you for your condition.

Comment: If your issue solved then you have to accept the answer so it can help other.

Comment: I did not really understand how this works... I really want to see a working example

Comment: Ok. From where are you want to search ?  i mean are you using the ArrayList for the List Out the data right ?? Reply me for your solution.

Comment: So, I have an array called classes and I populate my listview with those values. As the header of that list I have a button called search. When I click that button it calls the search intent. I have created a class called Search and I have modified my manifest as well. How do I search within that array? How do I display the results on a listview? Will it be easier to use autocomplete?

Comment: Ok. I got what you want. you want to write something in to the EditText, and based on that you want to search the data from the ListView. but tht Data should be Display to the Next Activity right ?? Is it so then My Code is work for that but for that you have to pass that search name to the Next Activity and put the above code. Still not solve then let me know. I will like to help. Thanks.

Comment: no I want the data to be displayed in the same activity. Thank you for your help btw

Comment: Ok So Just implement my code for the present search Activity. it will filter the data based on the search and display it on to listView during search time.

Answer (score 2):

This is not as straightforward as it might seem, but simple enough. You want to make your adapter (you need to have a custom adapter) implement the `Filterable` interface. Then when you "perform the filtering" you perform the query in the database and return the updated results, calling `notifyDatasetChanged()`. I couldn't find a good example quickly, but [this one](http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-adapter-for-autocomplete.aspx) is good enough.

After that, you need to "connect" both the adapter's filter and an EditText. Add a TextWatcher to the EditText and in the `afterTextChanged()` call `getFilter().filter(theText)`.

That's more or less it.

Comment: Thank you i will try to implement this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://paritoshranjan.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/android-database-implementation/

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html